# Subquery returned more than 1 value. wrong if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

if condition equal to true then I would like multiplication 
(od.price * od.kilo), and then bring the other fields 
else

I would like multiplication(od.quant * od.price) and then bring the other fields

CREATE PROC GET_ORDER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS
    @ORDERID INT

```
AS 
 BEGIN
        IF((SELECT calcType FROM orderDetailsTBL od WHERE od.orderID = @ORDERID) = 'K') 
            BEGIN
            SELECT
            (SELECT od.price * od.kilo FROM orderDetailsTBL od) as "AMOUNT",

            od.quant as "QUANTITY" , 
            od.kilo as "KILO" ,
            od.price as "PRICE" ,
            od.calcType as "UNIT" ,
            p.prodName as "NAME" ,
            od.recivedID as "RECIVED"
FROM orderAccTBL oa
JOIN orderDetailsTBL od ON od.orderID = oa.orderID
JOIN productTBL p ON p.prodID = od.productID
WHERE
        oa.orderID = @ORDERID
                    END
            ELSE

            BEGIN
            SELECT
            (SELECT od.quant * od.price FROM orderDetailsTBL od) as "AMOUNT",
            od.quant as "QUANTITY" , 
            od.kilo as "KILO" ,
            od.price as "PRICE" ,
            od.calcType as "UNIT" ,
            p.prodName as "NAME" ,
            od.recivedID as "RECIVED"
FROM orderAccTBL oa
JOIN orderDetailsTBL od ON od.orderID = oa.orderID
JOIN productTBL p ON p.prodID = od.productID
WHERE
        oa.orderID = @ORDERID
            END

    END
```

Comment: You need to explain what your problem is and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any of these IF..ELSE statements or even the sub-queries in your select, what you are after, can be achieved with the following simple select query:

```
CREATE PROC GET_ORDER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS
 @ORDERID INT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
          CASE 
               WHEN od.calcType = 'K'  
               THEN od.price * od.kilo 
               ELSE od.quant * od.price 
           END          as [AMOUNT]
         ,od.quant      as [QUANTITY] 
         ,od.kilo       as [KILO] 
         ,od.price      as [PRICE] 
         ,od.calcType   as [UNIT] 
         ,p.prodName    as [NAME] 
         ,od.recivedID  as [RECIVED]
    FROM       orderAccTBL     oa
    INNER JOIN orderDetailsTBL od ON od.orderID = oa.orderID
    INNER JOIN productTBL      p  ON p.prodID = od.productID
    WHERE oa.orderID = @ORDERID

END
```

Comment: incorrect syntax near @ORDERID

Comment: @MohamedHmmam I have just checked the query in the compiler and it is not showing any syntax errors, have you made any changes to the query before you tested it?

Comment: thank you , it was small mistake, now its work fine
thank you very much , and sorry for my bad english skills

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help :)